# Django CreateView form not submitting

Tags: python, html, django

My form has been working fine, until around 2 - 3 hours ago and I am not sure when it went wrong since I haven't tested it every time I made a change.

When I press submit to create the page and make it live, it doesn't do anything at all.

HTML:

```
{% extends 'public/base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block head %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "public/css/create-post.css" %}" />
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="container">
        <div class="form-create">
            <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form|crispy }}
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Publish">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block script %}
        tinymce.init({
            selector: '#id_text'
        });
        $("#id_created_date, #id_published_date").flatpickr();
{% endblock %}
```

Views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from .models import Post, Category
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView, CreateView, UpdateView

# Create your views here.

class IndexView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "public/index.html"

class PostEdit(object):
    model = Post
    fields = '__all__'
    success_url = '/'

class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, PostEdit, CreateView):
    success_url = '/'
    fields = ['title', 'text', 'category', 'image']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

class PostUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, PostEdit, UpdateView):
    success_url = '/'
    fields = ['title', 'text', 'category', 'image']

class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post

class CategoryView(ListView):
    model = Category
```

Would be great if someone could help! Thanks.

Comment: Do you have `DEBUG = True` in your settings.py? Any output from that?

Comment: @MikeO'Connor Yeah thats on. Getting no errors at all.

Comment: Your django code is correct. It seems like a Javascript issue. Disable Javascript and then submit the form.

Comment: @farooq You are correct. Commented out the js block and it works. Thanks for the help, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your django code is correct. It seems like a Javascript issue. Disable Javascript and then submit the form.

Comment: You can see that it is in in the code if you look at the HTML text block.